Github workflow issue with triggers
I have two Github workflow file in my folder. While triggering one workflow with Github Issues, the other workflow is also running but it is skipped. How do I fix this issue and need to run only one workflow job related to issue created?
I want to run only one workflow related to the issue that I created and the other job should not run in parallel.
